# Broadcast Receiver in Oreo and above

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I have a general question regarding broadcast receivers registration.
According to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts), starting Oreo (API 26), Google has restricted registering broadcast receivers in manifest for most implicit broadcasts. For example, I have an app that uses broadcast receiver that listening to bluetooth connection status, and launches a service when certain device get connected. **This receiver has to be registered in manifest** and not in Activity/Service (using registerReceiver).
I compiled it targeting API 26 and the broadcast receiver didn't fired. When I compiled the same code targeting API 24 it worked flawlessly.
I don't want keep targeting outdated API when compiling my apps, but I do need to use broadcast receiver that registered from manifest sometimes. What is the recommended way to accomplished this?

Comment: Are you using `ACL_CONNECTED` as your `intent-filter`? That broadcast is whitelisted (i.e., not subject to the restriction), so it should still be invoking your `BroadcastReceiver`. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Comment: @Slava pls share how u fixed this issue ? I m targeting 26 and broadcast not getting fired while using explicit broadcast receiver

Comment: I'm using API 24.

Comment: But then Play Store requires to target 26 Api right?